# INET 4.0 installation error OMNET++ 5.4.1 Linux Mint 19 XFCE

Tags: omnet++, linux-mint, inet

When I try to install **INET 4.0** on **fresh** Linux Mint 19 installation with OMNET++ v5.4.1 there is an error message like this:

[image]

Here is error text titled "Problem Occured"

```
Cannot download archive from https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/releases/download/v4.0.0/inet-4.0.0-src.tgz java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

When I try to reach the download address from command line with

`wget https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/releases/download/v4.0.0/inet-4.0.0-src.tgz`

mentioned at error screen I can download the INET 4.0 .tgz file.

Also I checked if I could reach internet by pinging.

How can I find what causes this? Any answers are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Eclipse internal error. No quick fix unless you want to get worked up in the Eclipse OMNET++ IDE internals.

Easiest solution: Go to the [INET website](https://inet.omnetpp.org/) or the [INET Github repository](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/releases) and download the archive of the latest INET 4.0 release.

Then just import the INET project ("Import --> Existing Project --> select Archive File") and voila, you got the INET project in your OMNeT++ installation.

Comment: In fact, this is a distro issue where the java certificate store is in incorrect format as it has changed with Java9. Most likely this happens if you have upgraded from an older version of the distro that came with Java8 as default. This might help to work around the issue: https://gist.github.com/mikaelhg/527204e746984cf9a33f7910bb8b4cb6